# How to read a directory in html5 from a folder picker input?

Tags: javascript, html, directory-structure

I want to have a input field that lets you select a folder. And then use html5 directory reader api to recursively read all files and folders in it.

Does anyone know any tutorials doing this specifically? I have code here, but it doesn't work, it always lists empty array when reading.

```
<input type="file" id="filepicker" name="fileList" webkitdirectory directory />
<button id="ff">Read</button>
<ul id="filelist"></ul>
```

js

```
function toArray(list) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(list || [], 0);
}

function listResults(entries) {
  // Document fragments can improve performance since they're only appended
  // to the DOM once. Only one browser reflow occurs.
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  entries.forEach(function(entry, i) {
    var img = entry.isDirectory ? '<img src="folder-icon.gif">' :
                                  '<img src="file-icon.gif">';
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = [img, '<span>', entry.name, '</span>'].join('');
    fragment.appendChild(li);
  });

  document.querySelector('#filelist').appendChild(fragment);
}

function onInitFs(fs) {

  var dirReader = fs.root.createReader();
  var entries = [];

  // Call the reader.readEntries() until no more results are returned.
  var readEntries = function() {
     dirReader.readEntries (function(results) {
      if (!results.length) {
        listResults(entries.sort());
      } else {
        entries = entries.concat(toArray(results));
        readEntries();
      }
    }, errorHandler);
  };

  readEntries(); // Start reading dirs.

}

function errorHandler(e) {
  var msg = '';

  switch (e.code) {
    case DOMError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
      msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
      break;
    case DOMError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
      msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
      break;
    case DOMError.SECURITY_ERR:
      msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
      break;
    case DOMError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
      break;
    case DOMError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
      break;
    default:
      msg = 'Unknown Error';
      break;
  };

  console.log('Error: ' + msg);
}



document.getElementById("ff").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var selectedFiledf = $("#filepicker").val();
    window.webkitRequestFileSystem(selectedFiledf, 1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 directory reader not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612697/html5-directory-reader-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a function attached to the onchange event of the file input.
When this function is called, you will be able to access the file list by accessing `event.target.files`.
Then, when the user presses the Read button, you can process the files.

```
var files;
document.getElementById("filepicker").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  files = event.target.files;
}, false);
```

This guide might be useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory